# Communication between ROS and wxWidgets

Tags: ros, c++, wxwidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the best way of sending and receiving ROS messages to and from a wxWidgets GUI in C++?
I have a GUI that should be updated with status of some ROS nodes and I want to be able to send some ROS messages to ROS nodes when a button is clicked i the GUI (or similar).

I have tried to make wxApp as a ROS node and update the GUI when a ROS message is received, but it does not work (some problems with threads).

There must be a 'default' way of communicating with other C++ programs in a wxWidgets GUI?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11936/communication-between-ros-and-wxwidgets/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it to work now. It turned out that I forgot to change the call to wxFrame, so the Frame that was supposed to be a class variable was actually a local variable. :-(
I'm so mad at myself that I didn't see that sooner...

Anyway, if someone else wants to connect ROS and wxWidgets, this is how I did it:

In wxApp:

- In OnInit(): call *ros::init()* (convert wxString in argv to char**)
- In Onrun(): create a nodehandle and call subscribe with a reference to the wxFrame object. End OnRun with *return wxApp::OnRun();*

In wxFrame:

- Create a timer event that calls *ros::spinonce()* in its callback method.
- Create a callback method for the ROS message and do some exciting stuff in it :-)

---

Originally posted by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) with karma: 328 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LivingMachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/2201/livingmachine/) on 2013-07-05**:
Hi Ola, I am trying to building a GUI with wxWidgets (using Code::Block). Can you point me where I can find the wxApp::OnRun()? Or where can I read more about it, please.

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-08-13**:
I don't think it is there by default, but you should place it in the App-class, so something like this:
int MyCoolApp::OnRun()
{
// subscribers and stuf goes here
return wxApp::OnRun();
}

**Comment by [Adri](https://answers.ros.org/users/25773/adri/) on 2016-02-16**:
Hello, Ola. I have some questions for you, I hope you can answer me.

When you said "Create a timer event that calls ros::spinonce() in its callback method.", did you mean that we have to create a wxTimerEvent? http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer_event.html

**Comment by [Adri](https://answers.ros.org/users/25773/adri/) on 2016-02-16**:
And the other question is: When you said "In OnInit(): call ros::init() (convert wxString in argv to char**)", which argv do you mean?

Thank you in advance.

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2016-02-16**:
Yes you should create a wxTimerEvent.
In onInit, I do the following:
char** argvForRos  = new char*[argc];
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
{
argvForRos[i] = strdup(wxString(argv[i]).mb_str());
}
ros::init(argc, _argvForRos, "my

Gui");

**Comment by [Adri](https://answers.ros.org/users/25773/adri/) on 2016-02-17**:
Thank you for your answer. In onInit I tried directly with a casting and it worked too: ros::init(argc, (char **) argv, "my_other_GUI");

Again, thank you so much, Ola. You helped me a lot, :)

**Comment by [shyamashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31162/shyamashi/) on 2021-06-16**:
Hi Ola, Thanks for the answer. However, I am new to C++ and hence struggling a bit. I have tried to incorporate all the things that you said but not working. I want to subscribe to an image from ROS and visualize in the GUI. I am sure there could be several errors in my code but if you could find sometime, please take a look at it https://github.com/ashBabu/Utilities/blob/master/guiTest.cpp, it would be really helpful. Specifically I am struggling to create the timer and 'call subscribe with a reference to the wxFrame objec'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have little experience with wxWidgets, but I can give a general answer for using ROS subscribers/publishers within a GUI framework.

First read http://answers.ros.org/question/2853/significance-of-rosspinonce#4581 and the roscpp overview of [callbacks and spinning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning). This is an example of "Integrating ROS with framework X."

Using ROS requires two things:

- **Initialization**: Call `ros::init(...)`, create a `ros::NodeHandle`, and create any `ros::Publisher`'s or `ros::Subscriber`'s you need.
- **Event handling**: Periodically (on the order of 10ms) call `ros::spinOnce()` to handle callbacks for any just-arrived messages.

In a simple ROS node, you'd do all that in your `main()`. Set up your ROS communication, and then call `ros::spin()` to handle events until the node shuts down.

Some GUI frameworks (like wxWidgets) claim `main()` entirely for themselves, so you have to slot these tasks into whatever hooks the framework gives you. In the framework's "On Init" hook, do your ROS initialization, and then set up a timer event (using whatever mechanism the framework provides) that calls `ros::spinOnce()`.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4